# Insert a Row in Excel Using Java Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am developing a desktop application related to Excel sheets. I have some problems  inserting rows between two rows. Is there any possibility to do this in Java using **Apache POI**?

```
Workbook wb3=WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("Book1.xls"));
Sheet sh=wb3.getSheet("sheet1");
```

`//Reading the available rows using (sh.getRow(1))`

`//Here i need to insert second row (????)`

`//I have third row here which already exists (sh.getRow(3))`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I have a solution which is working very well:

```
Workbook wb3=WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("Book1.xls"));
Sheet sh=wb3.getSheet("sheet1");  
int rows=sh.getLastRowNum();
```

Shift the number of rows down the sheet.

```
sh.shiftRows(2,rows,1);
```

Here

- `2`    -- Position at which we need to insert row
- `rows` -- Total rows
- `1`    -- How many rows we are going to insert

The reason why we are doing the above process is to make an empty row; only then can we create a new row.

*Now we shifted the rows, then we can do our stuff*

**Coding :**

```
sh.createRow(1);
```

The above code is used to insert a row at the 1st position, as we defined.

Comment: This is shifting the row content but not the row formatting. The formatting stays in place.