# Adding a row to a large xlsx file (Out of Memory)

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi, heap-memory

The situation is as follows;
I have a simple program which uses the Apache Poi Library to add one row of data at the end of the an exisiting xlsx file. See below

```
File file = new File(input);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1);
```

After this I will iterate over the row and set the CellValues. But the problem is that on the second line of the code, as shown above, I get an out of memory error. Is there a way to add a row of data to the existing xlsx file without having to read the file fully?

Comment: Chek thi one: **http://stackoverflow.com/a/18415433/1652222**

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I that case they also create a Workbook. This wil also cause a heap space error

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805878/add-content-to-a-very-large-excel-file-using-apache-poi-run-out-of-alternatives/35826943#35826943

Answer (score 1):

(not enough reputation to add this as a comment)
Have you tried using SXSSFWorkbook instead of XSSFWorkbook?

Comment: The SXSSFWorkbook can only write (more efficient than XSSF though), but then I still need to read the existing data from the current file in order to copy this data to the SXFFWorkbook. I believe, please correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can try [XSSF and SAX (Event API)](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#XSSF+and+SAX+%28Event+API%29).

Answer (score 1):

If getting the `XSSFWorkbook` fails because of out-of-memory error and the need is to read **and** write the workbook, then neither `SXSSF` nor `SAX` parser will help. The one is only for writing. The other is only for reading.

Both approaches in follow needs knowledge about the `*.xlsx` file format which is [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML). In general a `*.xlsx`  file is a `ZIP` archive  containing `XML` files and other files in a special directory structure. So one can unzip the `*.xlsx`  file using a `ZIP` software to have a look at the `XML` files. The file format was first standardized by Ecma. So for further recherches I prefer [Ecma Markup Language Reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/Office%20Open%20XML%20Part%204%20-%20Markup%20Language%20Reference.pdf). For example [Row](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/Office%20Open%20XML%20Part%204%20-%20Markup%20Language%20Reference.pdf#%5B2010%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C51%2C242%2C0%5D).

The `ReadAndWriteTest.xlsx` used in both examples must have at least one worksheet and the first worksheet must have at least one row.

One approach could be using the `DOM` methods of [XMLBeans](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/). My favorite reference for this is [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/WorksheetDocument.java).

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.WorksheetDocument;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorksheet;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheetData;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTRst;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTCell;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STCellType;

import  org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.relationships.STRelationshipId;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class DOMReadAndWriteTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   File file = new File("ReadAndWriteTest.xlsx");
   //we only open the OPCPackage, we don't create a Workbook
   OPCPackage opcpackage = OPCPackage.open(file);

   //if there are strings in the SheetData, we need the SharedStringsTable
   PackagePart sharedstringstablepart = opcpackage.getPartsByName(Pattern.compile("/xl/sharedStrings.xml")).get(0);
   SharedStringsTable sharedstringstable = new SharedStringsTable();
   sharedstringstable.readFrom(sharedstringstablepart.getInputStream());

   //get the PackagePart of the first sheet
   PackagePart sheetpart = opcpackage.getPartsByName(Pattern.compile("/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml")).get(0);
   //get the worksheet from the first sheet's XML
   //if it even fails while parsing this, then this approach is not usable
   WorksheetDocument worksheetdocument = WorksheetDocument.Factory.parse(sheetpart.getInputStream());
   CTWorksheet worksheet = worksheetdocument.getWorksheet();

   CTSheetData sheetdata = worksheet.getSheetData();

   //put some data in 10 new rows"
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int rowsCount = sheetdata.sizeOfRowArray();

    CTCell ctcell= sheetdata.addNewRow().addNewC();

    CTRst ctstr = CTRst.Factory.newInstance();
    ctstr.setT("new Row " + (rowsCount + 1));
    int sRef = sharedstringstable.addEntry(ctstr);
    ctcell.setT(STCellType.S);
    ctcell.setV(Integer.toString(sRef));

    ctcell=sheetdata.getRowArray(rowsCount).addNewC();
    ctcell.setV(""+rowsCount+"."+(i+1)+""+((i+2>9)?0:i+2));
   }

   //write the SharedStringsTable
   OutputStream out = sharedstringstablepart.getOutputStream();
   sharedstringstable.writeTo(out);
   out.close();

   //create XmlOptions for saving the worksheet
   XmlOptions xmlOptions = new XmlOptions();
   xmlOptions.setSaveOuter();
   xmlOptions.setUseDefaultNamespace();
   xmlOptions.setSaveAggressiveNamespaces();
   xmlOptions.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   xmlOptions.setSaveSyntheticDocumentElement(new QName(CTWorksheet.type.getName().getNamespaceURI(), "worksheet"));
   Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
   map.put(STRelationshipId.type.getName().getNamespaceURI(), "r");
   xmlOptions.setSaveSuggestedPrefixes(map);

   //save the worksheet
   out = sheetpart.getOutputStream();
   worksheet.save(out, xmlOptions);
   out.close();

   opcpackage.close();

  } catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

This code writes 10 new Rows in sheet1 of  `ReadAndWriteTest.xlsx` without opening the whole workbook. But it must at least opening and parsing the sheet1 and the `SharedStringsTable`. If even this fails, then this approach is not usable.

Another approach could be using [StAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/index.html). This API can read and write XML event driven. And it uses streaming.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTRst;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventWriter;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.events.Characters;
import javax.xml.stream.events.StartElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.EndElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.Attribute;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class StaxReadAndWriteTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   File file = new File("ReadAndWriteTest.xlsx");
   OPCPackage opcpackage = OPCPackage.open(file);

   //if there are strings in the sheet data, we need the SharedStringsTable
   //if it even fails while parsing this SharedStringsTable, then this approach is not usable
   //then we must stream this XML event driven also.
   PackagePart sharedstringstablepart = opcpackage.getPartsByName(Pattern.compile("/xl/sharedStrings.xml")).get(0);
   SharedStringsTable sharedstringstable = new SharedStringsTable();
   sharedstringstable.readFrom(sharedstringstablepart.getInputStream());

   PackagePart sheetpart = opcpackage.getPartsByName(Pattern.compile("/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml")).get(0);

   XMLEventReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(sheetpart.getInputStream());
   XMLEventWriter writer = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventWriter(sheetpart.getOutputStream());

   XMLEventFactory eventFactory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();

   int rowsCount = 0;

   while(reader.hasNext()){ //loop over all XML in sheet1.xml
    XMLEvent event = (XMLEvent)reader.next();
    writer.add(event); //by default write each readed event

    if(event.isStartElement()){
     StartElement startElement = (StartElement)event;
     QName startElementName = startElement.getName();
     if(startElementName.getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("row")) { //start element of row
      boolean rowStart = true;
      rowsCount++;
      do {
       event = (XMLEvent)reader.next(); //find this row's end
       writer.add(event); //by default write each readed event

       if(event.isEndElement()){
        EndElement endElement = (EndElement)event;
        QName endElementName = endElement.getName();
        if(endElementName.getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("row")) { //end element of row
         rowStart = false;
         //we assume that there is nothing else (character data) between end element of row and next element 
         XMLEvent nextElement = (XMLEvent)reader.peek();
         QName nextElementName = null;
         if (nextElement.isStartElement()) nextElementName = ((StartElement)nextElement).getName();
         else if (nextElement.isEndElement()) nextElementName = ((EndElement)nextElement).getName();
         if(!nextElementName.getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("row")) { //next is not start element of row
          //we have the last row, so we write new rows now 

          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

           StartElement newRowStart = eventFactory.createStartElement(new QName("row"), null, null);
           writer.add(newRowStart);

//start cell A
           Attribute attribute = eventFactory.createAttribute("t", "s");
           List attributeList = Arrays.asList(attribute);
           StartElement newCellStart = eventFactory.createStartElement(new QName("c"), attributeList.iterator(), null);
           writer.add(newCellStart);

           CTRst ctstr = CTRst.Factory.newInstance();
           ctstr.setT("new Row " + (rowsCount +1));
           int sRef = sharedstringstable.addEntry(ctstr);

           StartElement newCellValue = eventFactory.createStartElement(new QName("v"), null, null);
           writer.add(newCellValue);

           Characters value = eventFactory.createCharacters(Integer.toString(sRef));
           writer.add(value);         

           EndElement newCellValueEnd = eventFactory.createEndElement(new QName("v"), null);
           writer.add(newCellValueEnd);

           EndElement newCellEnd = eventFactory.createEndElement(new QName("c"), null);
           writer.add(newCellEnd);
//end cell A
//start cell B
           newCellStart = eventFactory.createStartElement(new QName("c"), null, null);
           writer.add(newCellStart);

           newCellValue = eventFactory.createStartElement(new QName("v"), null, null);
           writer.add(newCellValue);

           value = eventFactory.createCharacters(""+rowsCount+"."+(i+1)+""+((i+2>9)?0:i+2));
           writer.add(value);         

           newCellValueEnd = eventFactory.createEndElement(new QName("v"), null);
           writer.add(newCellValueEnd);

           newCellEnd = eventFactory.createEndElement(new QName("c"), null);
           writer.add(newCellEnd);
//end cell B

           EndElement newRowEnd = eventFactory.createEndElement(new QName("row"), null);
           writer.add(newRowEnd);

           rowsCount++;
          }
         }
        }
       }
      } while (rowStart);
     }
    }
   }

   writer.flush();

   //write the SharedStringsTable
   OutputStream out = sharedstringstablepart.getOutputStream();
   sharedstringstable.writeTo(out);
   out.close();

   opcpackage.close();

  } catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

This code also writes 10 new Rows in sheet1 of  `ReadAndWriteTest.xlsx` without opening the whole workbook. But it must at least opening and parsing the `SharedStringsTable`. If even this fails, then this approach is also not usable. But of course even the `SharedStringsTable` could be streamed using StAX. But as you see in example with generating the rows and cells, this is much more complicated. So using the `SharedStringsTable` makes things easier in this example.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Unfortunately the file is to big to open (and parse) with both approaches.