# java apache poi shifting Rows runs into a runtime exception

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a simple excel sheet with basic excel formulas, such as sums, and value retrieval from another cell. Now, I want to essentially insert a blank line in between two existing lines (I've taken a look at [How to insert a row between two rows in an existing excel with HSSF (Apache POI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785724/how-to-insert-a-row-between-two-rows-in-an-existing-excel-with-hssf-apache-poi), but I'm running into some strange errors).

So I tried shifting rows by doing this:

```
worksheet.shiftRows(15,16,2);
```

and I'm getting this in return:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: not implemented yet
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.getExternalSheetIndex(XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.java:127)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.createAreaRefParseNode(FormulaParser.java:615)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeable(FormulaParser.java:462)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeExpression(FormulaParser.java:268)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseSimpleFactor(FormulaParser.java:1119)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.percentFactor(FormulaParser.java:1079)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.powerFactor(FormulaParser.java:1066)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Term(FormulaParser.java:1426)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.additiveExpression(FormulaParser.java:1526)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.concatExpression(FormulaParser.java:1510)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.comparisonExpression(FormulaParser.java:1467)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.unionExpression(FormulaParser.java:1447)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:1568)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:176)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.helpers.XSSFRowShifter.updateNamedRanges(XSSFRowShifter.java:116)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.shiftRows(XSSFSheet.java:2363)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.shiftRows(XSSFSheet.java:2306)
    at com.shel.myProgram.workbook.copyAndInsert(workbook.java:120)
    at com.shel.myProgram.workbook.test(workbook.java:111)
    at com.shel.myProgram.driver.main(driver.java:24)
```

EDIT:

I'm using this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Take a look at **org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFEvaluationWorkbook** line 127. May be in your library this function is "not implemented yet"

Comment: @ThrashBean I'm getting 127 is not a valid number in org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFEvaluationWorkbook ... I'm so confused. In fact the file appears to be empty. I'm using apache poi version 3.9

Comment: Yes, it's not implemented. Neither is in 3.10-beta2, nor in 3.11-beta1 (the latest nightly build). So you have to look for other way to do this. Just curious - are you using xlsx?

Comment: yes, macro enabled though. @ThrashBean

Comment: Sorry about you, look for something different, this will not work.

Comment: Looks like you have a problematic named range that POI is struggling to update for the shift. Any chance you could post any non-standard named ranges you have in the sheet?

Comment: I have the same problem. For simple file shiftRows method works fine, but if I run this method for large file, it shows me the same error as for user ~ Stupid.Fat.Cat My version POI is 3.10. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There was a lot of work on this part of the code of POI lately, so it would be interesting what happens if you run it with a current nightly build!

Answer (score 0):

Try This. `sheet.shiftRows(currentRow, sheet.getLastRowNum()+1, amount, true,true);`