# Shift row of a xlsx file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm reading an Excel file with some rows through POI. I have to delete the row of the file if it is correctly saved on the DB.

Until a few day ago, I was working with a .xls file (HSSFSheet) and everything worked fine.
[Removing a row from a HSSFSHEET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635360/java-apache-poi-shifting-rows-runs-into-a-runtime-exception)

Now I need some more of the 256 columns of the .xls file and then I changed it to a XSSFSheet. But when I use it I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: not implemented yet
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.getExternalSheetIndex(XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.java:117)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.createAreaRefParseNode(FormulaParser.java:613)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeable(FormulaParser.java:508)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeExpression(FormulaParser.java:266)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseSimpleFactor(FormulaParser.java:1117)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.percentFactor(FormulaParser.java:1077)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.powerFactor(FormulaParser.java:1064)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Term(FormulaParser.java:1424)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.additiveExpression(FormulaParser.java:1524)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.concatExpression(FormulaParser.java:1508)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.comparisonExpression(FormulaParser.java:1465)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Arguments(FormulaParser.java:1049)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.function(FormulaParser.java:934)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseNonRange(FormulaParser.java:556)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeable(FormulaParser.java:427)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeExpression(FormulaParser.java:266)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseSimpleFactor(FormulaParser.java:1117)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.percentFactor(FormulaParser.java:1077)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.powerFactor(FormulaParser.java:1064)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseUnary(FormulaParser.java:1129)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseSimpleFactor(FormulaParser.java:1102)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.percentFactor(FormulaParser.java:1077)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.powerFactor(FormulaParser.java:1064)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Term(FormulaParser.java:1424)
```

I'm using these POI dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I saw [Shift rows exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635360/java-apache-poi-shifting-rows-runs-into-a-runtime-exception).

In this post you say that also the last release of POI hasn't implemented the method yet.

This is my code.

```
public void import(){

    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteUploaded));   
    List<Row> rowsToRemoved = new ArrayList<Row>();
    Sheet mySheet =  wbUploaded.getSheetAt(0);

    for(Row row: mySheet){

        try{

            MyDTO dto = checkRow(row);
            importService.save(dto);
            rowsToRemoved.add(row);

        }catch(Exception e){
            //do something
        }
    }
    deleteRowSavedFromSheet(mySheet,rowsToRemoved);

}

public void deleteRowSavedFromSheet(Sheet sheet, List<Row> rowsToRemoved ) {

    for(Row row : rowsToRemoved){

        sheet.removeRow(row); 
        int lastRowNum=sheet.getLastRowNum();
        if(rowIndex>=0&&rowIndex<lastRowNum){
            sheet.shiftRows(rowIndex+1,lastRowNum, -1); //here i get the exception
        }
        if(rowIndex==lastRowNum){
            Row removingRow=sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
            if(removingRow!=null){
                sheet.removeRow(removingRow);
            }
        }   
    }

    rowsToRemoved.clear();
}
```

How can I use the shift method?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21956362/624003

Comment: I try to use WorkbookFactory.create but it not work i get the same error

Comment: Share your code with us

Answer (score 0):

From [Apache poi documentation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/)

> HSSF is the POI Project's pure Java implementation of the Excel '97(-2007) file format. XSSF is the POI Project's pure Java implementation of the Excel 2007 OOXML (.xlsx) file format.

You can not use `XSSF` with a `xls` file.

Comment: But I'm using an xlsx file not a xls

Comment: That's not what you're saying in your question : `Now I need some more of the 256 columns of the .xls file`

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have consecutive rows use the following method

```
public static void deleteRowSavedFromSheet(Sheet sheet, List<Row> rowsToRemoved){
    for(Row row : rowsToRemoved){
        sheet.shiftRows(row.getRowNum()+1, sheet.getLastRowNum(), -1);
    }

}
```

and if you have consecutive rows, simply use

```
sheet.shiftRows(lastIndexOfRowToRemove +1, LastIndexOfSheet, -CountOfRowsToRemove)
```

It may cause problem for last row deletion... so for that case, you should use delete row

Comment: I can't try it now, but i think that this don't will resolve the trouble, because i get the exception on sheet.shiftRows() call