# Creating new rows with NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I have a table in an excel document (.xlsx), which serves as a report template.
I'd like to create a specific number of new rows in that template, at a specific row index, and also copy the format/style of the row before the new rows.

I tried various combination of the `ShiftRows()` method:

```
sheet.ShiftRows(18, 20, 1); // this inserts one empty line, but doesn't copy the format of the line between 18 and 20.
```

As I understand this function, the line 19, which is between 18 and 20, should be copied and moved 1x down, but the format of line 19 is not copied. However, if I execute the following snippet, it doesn't create three new rows:

```
sheet.ShiftRows(18, 20, 1);
sheet.ShiftRows(18, 20, 1);
sheet.ShiftRows(18, 20, 1);
```

The following snippet creates three new lines, but doesn't copy the format of the shifted row:

```
sheet.ShiftRows(18, 20, 3);
```

Would anybody know how this should be handled?

Answer (score 0):

please check the link [How to insert a row between two rows in an existing excel with HSSF (Apache POI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785724/how-to-insert-a-row-between-two-rows-in-an-existing-excel-with-hssf-apache-poi) . Although code explained for is for POI library but all functionality of NPOI and POI are common for HSSF and XSSF.