# How to copy/write particular row using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I know i am missing the main function here. I want to copy/ write only particular row from my source excel to destination excel using apache POI.

eg. My source excel has 10 rows. I need only 5th row to be copied to my destination excel.

My class,

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        File srcFile=new File("C:\\Test\\Read.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(srcFile);

        XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet1=wb.getSheetAt(0);

        File desFile=new File("C:\\Test\\Write.xlsx");
        FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(desFile);

        wb.write(fout);

        wb.close();     
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is Selenium tagged here? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Apache POI docs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html), you can use the `XSSFSheet.getRow(int)` method to get a row at a specific index.

```
// 5th row
Row row = sheet.getRow(4);
```

To add this row to a new workbook, you'll have to iterate through each cell in the `row` object and set the value of cells in the new workbook to these values. An example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5786426/3813669).

Comment: sheet.getRow(4) return null exception